# if change a file attribute to hidden when it is running, will it affected the process?

Tags: windows

if change a file attribute to hidden when it is running, will it affected the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the "hidden" attribute only affects visibility of the file, and does not affect your ability to access the file as long as you actually know its full path.  Certainly, if you know where a hidden file is, you can navigate to it by typing the full path name and file name into Explorer.

See [this article](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial62.html) at Bleeping Computer for a little more information.  Also, check out the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory) entry on hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not.

The EXE file's attributes have no effect on the process at all, whether you change them before or after you launch it.